# urllib2 failing with https websites

Tags: python, urllib2

Using urllib2 and trying to get an https page, it keeps failing with

```
Invalid url, unable to resolve
```

The url is 
https://www.domainsbyproxy.com/default.aspx
but I have this happening on multiple https sites.

I am using python 2.7, and below is the code I am using to setup the connection

```
opener = urllib2.OpenerDirector()
opener.add_handler(urllib2.HTTPHandler())
opener.add_handler(urllib2.HTTPDefaultErrorHandler())
opener.addheaders = [('Accept-encoding', 'gzip')]
fetch_timeout = 12
response = opener.open(url, None, fetch_timeout)
```

The reason I am setting handlers manually is because I don't want redirects handled (which works fine). The above works fine for http requests, however https - fails.

Any clues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using HTTPSHandler instead of HTTPHandler

Comment: Interesting, I just assumed. I wonder if that means I also have to do HTTPSDefaultErrorHandler

Comment: apparantly HTTPSDefaultErrorHandler doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind external libraries, consider the excellent [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) module. It takes care of these quirks with urllib.

Your code, using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) is:

```
import requests
r = requests.get(url, headers={'Accept-encoding': 'gzip'}, timeout=12)
```

Comment: This looks pretty good, shame i've written all the code for my project already, but will use in the future.